# Mongoimport ignore leading zero in csv

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoimport, mongorestore

I have a `.CSV` export file from a SQL Server database, with a phone number field (number type) that field values started with leading zero.

Leading zero is presented in the CSV file.

When I attempt to mongoimport it to DB (in string type) I find data imported without leading zero.

The target field number is string. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specifically define the type of the field using the import option `--columnsHaveTypes`

> Instructs mongoimport that the field list specified in --fields, --fieldFile, or --headerline specifies the types of each field.

[MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/#cmdoption-mongoimport-columnshavetypes)